# Send POST Request via AWS Lambda in Node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I want to send a POST Request to Twilio when an Intent is called from my Alexa Skill. When testing the Code, there are no errors, but the Request doesn't seem to go through. Testing the POST Request in Postman works.

```
function postToTwilio() {

var http = require("https");
var postData = JSON.stringify({
      'To' : '1234567',
      'From': '1234546',
      'Url': 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/blablabla',


  });

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "https://api.twilio.com",
  "path": "/12344/Accounts/blablablablba/Calls.json",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic blblablablablabla",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();

}
```

Comment: You don't have an error handler on `req`, try adding one there and seeing if any errors are reported then. As written it's possible they are just not being handled. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) for more information.

Comment: I think you Lambda fuction has been finished before the post request finish, show where you use `postToTwilio ` function, and call callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a request is a async call so you need to make alexa wait for the response.

To do that, you need to use async await process and using promises.

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({
      'To' : '1234567',
      'From': '1234546',
      'Url': 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/blablabla',


  });

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "https://api.twilio.com",
  "path": "/12344/Accounts/blablablablba/Calls.json",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic blblablablablabla",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  }
};

function get(options) {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
        return reject(new Error(`${response.statusCode}: ${response.req.getHeader('host')} ${response.req.path}`));
      }

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.write(postData)
    request.end();
  }));
}
```

Then, when you call this get function:

`let response = await get(options)`

I haven't tested as a whole but that is the base skeleton.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hey ,thank you for the reply! I copied everything you did. Just one question, when calling the get function (let response = await api.get(options) what should I input instead of the "api"? I am getting the message: "unexpected token api"

Comment: Sorry, just called get(...).   
I usually have that call in external class so I always call it as api.whatever

Updated the answer